# C++, BTree Insert

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-tree, c++17

Hi this is a code from my SearchTree class.
Node* is a structure whith m_info type int, and m_left(smaller nodes by info) and m_right(bigger nodes by info)

```
void SearchTree::insert(const int &x) {
  Node* tempo = m_root;
  while (tempo != nullptr) {
    if (tempo->m_info >= x) {
      tempo = tempo->m_left;
    } else {
      tempo = tempo->m_right;
    }
  }
  tempo = new Node(x);
}
```

I am trying to insert a new node to the tree.
But looks like I am missing something in memory  management. 
There tempo is a pointer to a new node, however it is not being related to m_root.
I am confused here. I really love the power of c++ but it bends my logic.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't save the pointer in tempo only. Tempo is a copy of your current position in the tree. You have to assign it to actual variable.

My solution to this problem would be to check if child is nullptr before you iterate

```
void SearchTree::insert(const int &x) {
  if (!m_root) {
      m_root = new Node(x);
      return;
  }
  Node* tempo = m_root;
  while (true) {
    if (tempo->m_info >= x) {
      if (!tempo->m_left) {
        tempo->m_left = new Node(x);
        return;
      }
      tempo = tempo->m_left;
    } else {
      if (!tempo->m_right) {
        tempo->m_right = new Node(x);
        return;
      }
      tempo = tempo->m_right;
    }
  }
}
```

Also you should use smart pointers instead of raw pointers.

An alternative solution is a pointer to pointer. I didn't test it but you can try

```
void SearchTree::insert(const int &x) {
  Node** tempo = &m_root;
  while (*tempo) {
    if ((*tempo)->m_info >= x) {
      tempo = &(*tempo)->m_left;
    } else {
      tempo = &(*tempo)->m_right;
    }
  }
  *tempo = new Node(x);
}
```

[image]

In this image you can see. If you use `Node* tempo = m_root` then `tempo` contains a copy of the value in `m_root`. If you change `tempo` then `m_root` stays unchanged.

If you use `Node** tempo = &m_root` then `tempo` is pointer to `m_root`. You can change `m_root` through `tempo`.

Comment: I don't know about smart pointers yet.
Looks good to me. But I would like a more elegant solution . if possible

Comment: I added a more "elegant" solution.

Comment: Yes it works. Great this is exactly what i was looking for. Now I just need to understand it

Comment: In the first solution `tempo` is a copy of the node. That means, if you change the value of `tempo` you don't change the node. In the second solution tempo is a pointer to the node address. This way you can change the address.

Comment: Aah. Awesome. Thank you!!
is this kind of solution a good practice in software development ?

Comment: Good practice means that it is readable. If you have difficulties to read it it's not good practice. But with more experience you will understand this fast. This is a usual way to pass a pointer by reference to a function, In c code you will find this pattern very often.

Comment: When I dont understand this kind of code, I draw the memory , and then I write a comment for every logical line. So I understand it.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

You keep advancing `tempo` until it is equal to `nullptr`. At this point you have left the tree and all you have in hand is a pointer into nothingness. Note that in particular the program has no way of determining which node you last visited that led to `tempo` becoming `null`.

What you need to do instead is stop one step *earlier*: While `tempo` is still pointing to a node, but the next step would make it point to `null`. Now you still have a valid node of the tree in your hand and can attach the newly allocated node to it.

Comment: Okay I can keep another variable , the parent of the tempo.

Comment: @R0xx0rZzz Yes, that's one way to do it. Please consider accepting the answer if you feel it answers your question. Happy to hear you understood the problem!

Comment: But, look what should I do when m_root is null?
I dont want to have an if statement to check in every insert

Comment: @R0xx0rZzz: I'd have the `if` personally, but your other option is to have a dummy root for the tree.